# Spacing of fractions with prime denominator

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $X\ge 2$ be large. Let $$A = \left\{\frac{a}{q}: 1\le a < q\le X,\ (a, q) = 1\right\},$$ and let $$B = \left\{\frac{a}{p}: 1\le a < p\le X,\ (a, p) = 1,\text{ and $p$ is prime}\right\}.$$ Note that for distinct $\frac{a}{q}, \frac{a'}{q'}\in A$, we have $$\left\lVert \frac{a}{q} - \frac{a'}{q'}\right\rVert\ge\frac{1}{qq'}\ge\frac{1}{X^2},\quad\text{where}\quad\lVert\beta\rVert := \min_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |\beta - n|.$$ It  follows that in any interval of length $X^{-2}$ in $[0, 1]$, there are at most $O(1)$ elements of $A$, and this is clearly the best result possible, since  $|A|\gg X^2$. Is it possible to get better results for $B$, since we have that $|B|\asymp X^2 / \log X$ by the prime number theorem. In particular, is it possible to get a bound of $o(\log X)$ for the number of elements of $B$ in an interval of length $$|B|^{-1}\ll X^{-2}\log X?$$ Note that the inclusion $B\subseteq A$ gives the trivial bound $O(\log X)$.

Comment: With the current definition, we have $B = \{ A\}$, are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: @Dirk, I'm guessing OP has forgotten to tell us that $p$ is restricted to being a prime.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm trying to make sense of the displayed inequality. What if $a/q=1/X$, and $a'/q'=1/2$, so $|(a/q)-(a'/q')|$ is roughly $1/2$? Is the inequality just the wrong way aroound?

Comment: I've corrected these typos. The inequality was originally the wrong way around.

Comment: I wonder whether the paper Harman, Glyn, Numbers badly approximable by fractions with prime denominator, Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 118 (1995), no. 1, 1–5, MR1329453 (96c:11080) is relevant here.

Comment: I think that would provide a bound of $O(\log\log X)$ if the set of such $\alpha$ were dense in [0, 1], but I'm not sure that is even true.

Comment: I have also found the paper, Xiong and Zaharescu, Pair correlation of rationals with prime denominators, J Number Theory 128 (2008) 2795-2807, which studies the pair correlation of the set $B$ as $X\to\infty$. I don't have the time now to see whether it (or any of the many apers it references) answers the question posed here.

Comment: This type of inequality on fractions is the starting point of the large sieve inequality.
In case that you are actually interested in applications with the large sieve:
Wolke observed that the sieve estimates with prime denominators can almost save the log factor:
Wolke, D. On the large sieve with primes.
Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar. 22 (1971/72), 239–247. 
https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=291121

Answer (score 1):

Wolke (On the large sieve with primes, Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar. 22 (1971/72), 239–247, MathSciNet MR0291121 (45 #215)) has worked on this question. His motivation was Gallagher's approach to the large sieve. If I remember correctly, his result was almost saving a factor $\log x$, which is what one would expect.